# Can't find why my javascript breaks encoding of my html

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, character-encoding

Hey everybody and thanks for your time,

I have an html page working well alone no encoding problem but if I include a js script it breaks encoding on my accentuated characters and I end up with a bunch of "Ã" and "©" and "Å".

I could put the two files here but their kinda big.

I've tried two things until now:

- Setting up the meta charset utf8 tag in the head of my html
- Setting up charset utf8 as attribute in my script's calling tag
- Checked encoding of files with "file -bi " they're all ut-8

I'm doing little DOM manipulation in my JS, the encoding is brokken even on strings that the JS doesn't manipulate at all.

I don't know how to solve this kind of encoding problem any hint will be greatly appreciated thanks !

Comment: Why does I get downvoted is my question no enought precise ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which editor you are using but take a look at the encoding you are saving the files with. For example in "Atom", its in the bottom right corner.
The encoding they are saved with has to match the encoding in the meta tag

Comment: Thanks, I had trouble with atom encoding by the past but they're all UTF-8 files, still I gonna investigate ty ! I gonna try conv command to see if it does something.